# subscribeOn Android UI thread

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I am new to RxJava and I think I am probably overlooking something very basic. So I have created an `Observable` that performs a long running I/O task like this. Now I want to make sure that subscriber receives its result on Android UI Thread:

```
Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Device>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull final ObservableEmitter<Device> e) throws Exception {
        //Long running task
    }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

As you can see, I have performed the long running task on `Schedulers.io()`. How do I switch back to Android UI thread?

Comment: Look on "observeOn" operator and "rxAndroid" library.

Comment: I know about `observeOn`. Is there any other workaround aside from using another library?

Comment: use the RxAndroid lib. It is only 1 or 2 methods, so not downsides to using it

Comment: Of course, you have another solution - you can implement your own Scheduler with main thread looper. Look into RxAndroid for example =)

But why you need to re-invent a bicycle, if you have the ability to load simple and light-weight library?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to perform `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`.

Comment: There is no `AndroidSchedulers` class.

Comment: You have to import [`RxAndroid`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) in gradle file:  `compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'`

Comment: Fascinating. I was reluctant to include another library, but it seems like it's very lightweight.

Comment: If you don't want to import that lib (but I suggest you to do it) just pass a scheduler construct with the main looper

Comment: @MathieuBertin Then why use RxAndroid at all?

Comment: Because it's just sugar but it's really usefull and it's really light. Moreover you have to implement your proper version of scheduler and it could not work properly instead of the 'AndroidSchedulers''